# How to use window.location.href in ComponentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs

I want to update state via `ComponentWillMount()` like:

```
this.state = {
  Canonical:''
}
componentWillMount(){
  this.setState({Canonical: window.location.href})
}
```

Anybody have idea how to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I wrote it onto a CodePen, and seems to be working for me... https://codepen.io/leogoesger/pen/gjrBYY?editors=1012

Comment: there is no output showing in codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/leogoesger/pen/gjrBYY?editors=1011 I think it was black on black, but the location was rendered. Is this what you are asking though?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **componentDidMount** method. 
This lifecycle method is invoked after the mounting of component and the same time it invokes **componentWillMount**.

setting state re-renders the component.

Another option is you initialise the state value in constructor.

```
 constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        Canonical: window.location.href
      }
    }
```

or

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({Canonical: window.location.href})
}
```

Comment: Yes this. Just do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid async initialization in `componentWillMount()`

`componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before `render()`, therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-render. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

Make async calls for component initialization in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`

```
function componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`api/messages`)
    .then((result) => {
      const messages = result.data
      console.log("COMPONENT WILL Mount messages : ", messages);
      this.setState({
        messages: [...messages.content]
      })
    })
}
```

> Note that `componentWillMount` is depreciated because it is not safe for async rendering

React: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Good read: https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b

Comment: hey @Jee thanks for reply, but I need to update and use that state at same time which is not possible in ComponentDidMount. That's why I want to use WillMount method.

Comment: no worries. `window` is client-side only, is it not possible in `componentWillMount()`. Can you describe what are you trying to do, so we can suggest an alternative solution to achieve it

Comment: I want to add Canonical Tag. I've tried to add in header file but it is not getting effected. So finally I've added into menu component, where I am using above mentioned functionality.

Comment: how are you using the tag?

Comment: <link rel="canonical" href={this.state.Canonical}/> //inside menu component

Comment: and in header file <link rel="canonical" href={window.location.href}/>

Comment: I see, if you use `href={this.state.canonical}` and when you update the state in `componentDidMount()` wouldn't it be updated correctly as well?

Comment: when app is rendered this.state.Canonical is empty, after rendering componentDidMount updating the state. Thats why i was trying to use WillMount method.

Comment: I want to tell you Even I delete header file content it does not effecting on app. I am using keystone with reactjs is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar I've written this pen: https://codepen.io/jeemok/pen/JBYxXQ

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar probably there is other issue with your react app. Perhaps sharing more code/config of your app would help us to debug easily

Comment: I've seen codepan, may be you are right there could be issue in app. let me figure it out. Thanks @JeeMok

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar no worries!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setState while initializing then

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    Canonical : window.location.href
  };
}
```

or if you want to update the state on componentWillMount then

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     Canonical : ''
   };
}

componentWillMount(){
  this.setState({ Canonical : window.location.href });
}
```

componentWillMount function will call before the render function. If something went wrong in componentWillMount the component won't render. it will block better you can try with componentDidMount(); function this function will be called after the render function in the component

```
Class Component{
  //sample structure of component and the flow
  componentWillMount(){}
  render(){}
  componentDidMount(){}
}
```

If you are using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) then you can call it like : `this.props.location` its a feature in that package 
to know more : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location